# Ubuntu - Terminal closes when I type command?

Tags: bash, shell, rake, bundler, gnome-terminal

`export PS1="\e[48;5;88m\e[38;5;15m\e[K\e[1m\t \e[38;5;82m\u\e[38;5;15m@\e[38;5;82m\h\e[38;5;15m on: \W [\e[38;5;82m\$\e[38;5;15m]\e[0m\n"`

With this variable set in .bashrc, exerytime I type `exec bundle rake db:migrate`.

I don't know what is wrong with the colors commands.

I use GNOME Terminal 3.18.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command `exec bundle...` should be `bundle exec...`. Running the `exec` command replaces your shell process with the proceeding command.